# 'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, in psql

Tags: windows, postgresql, psql

I installed PostgreSQL and pgAdmin 4 on windows 10. Everything works in pgAdmin, but when i try to use psql i get this error:

[image]

After running 'help', i can not run any option such as ? or \q. If i do, i get this error:

'more' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I found the chcp file in my Windows\System32. I assume it is the path that this file should be in. Also, i added  C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin to my environmental variable and C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\lib to my system variable in PTAH. I restarted the windows expecting it to work, but it does not. Any idea what i should do here?

Thanks

Comment: You are starting a batch file which contains invalid commands and then starts `psql`. Just open a command line window and start `psql.exe` manually to avoid those errors. But you do have an extremely unusual Windows installation. `chcp.exe` should be available in every Windows system.

Comment: chcp is a Windows command line command and has nothing to do with PostgreSQL.
how does it get into psql ?

Comment: @SergeyZakharov: eh329 is not running `psql.exe`, but a batch file that tries to be "more user friendly" than `psql` for Windows users that have no idea what a "command line" is. I think the idea was flawed from the start and EDB should simply stop adding something like that during installation.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I followed your advice. After running the psql.exe in CMD, it asks for password. When i enter my password, i get a new error: psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user

Comment: @eh329, bring at least a piece of your batch file

Comment: @eh329, the error "password authentication failed for user " occurs most likely due to the fact that an incorrect encoding is used, which is actually written in your screenshot, that the encoding does not match the console encoding.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer. I just copied the 'chcp', 'find' and 'more' files' from Windows/System32 and pasted them in C:\Users and now everything is working.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem.  What worked for me was adding Windows/System32 to my PATH.  That should give access to chcp (as well as a bunch more commands you will need for PSQL command line).  This also would explain why you can't run chcp from the command line and why moving the "chcp" and "more" files to "Users" would fix the issue (I'm guessing your users folder is somewhere in your PATH)

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to guess, you need to run chcp on the command line, and then run psql

```
chcp 1252
psql
```

Comment: I get this error:
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @eh329 , are you doing this on the windows command line? (cmd.exe)

Comment: Zakharov, Yes i did.

Comment: @eh329, Very strange, what version of Windows?

Comment: It is windows 10 version 21H2.

Comment: @eh329, chcp must be run inside a windows batch file (.bat, .cmd) and not inside a psql script. This is true?

Answer (score 0):

Add a PATH variable pointing to System32.
Below are links to images that will provide you a detailed explanation.

Image 1:
[Confirm the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7UoA.png)

Image 2:
[Add PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3HUg.png)

Image 3:
[Enter PATH as directed in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCnPB.png)

Image 4:
[After successfully completing the steps confirm the error is gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WFjd.png)